# Running 'goimports' on save in GoLand

Tags: go, goland

I'm using GoLand IDE to code in Go.
When I save a file, I'd like that the unused imports disappear (like VS code)

I have enable "Optimize imports" in "Code" -> "Show reformat file dialog". But when I save the file, imports it's still present

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## As of version 2021.3

Two separate entries were added to the File Watchers that are enabled by default. One for formatting the code on save, one for optimising the imports on save:

[image]

How the imports are sorted, grouped, etc. can be further defined in the Code Style settings for Go:

[image]

There is another small option to run `gofmt` on reformat in the `Other` tab of Go's Code Style settings:

[image]

## Before version 2021.3

The setting to set up `gofmt` or `goimports` on save is in the File Watchers. Here you can add a new file watcher at the bottom and select `gofmt` or `goimports` from the list.

[image]

Setting this to `goimports` will do both:

- code formatting (`gofmt`)
- updating, sorting and grouping imports

Comment: Hi, I have already see that option but I have setting it on "go ftm" to format code.. Unfortunately it can have only one action during "on save"

Comment: This is really impossible to use as with Goland constantly saving the source file I'm editing I'm effectively fighting `goimports` all the time: if I don't type quick enough (and I mean reeeally quick) `goimports` will just delete the code as I'm typing it…

Comment: Goland shouldn't autosave while you are typing. Or maybe you changed that setting? I think the default is: autosave after 15sec inactivity.

But I had that issue sometimes as well. Not seen it lately though. Maybe my new Notebook is too fast.

Comment: You have to install [File Watchers](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177-file-watchers) plugin if you are using IntelliJ IDEA with Go plugin

Comment: Thank you! The code style settings are what I was missing. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't organizing imports.

Answer (score 10):

"On Save" tab was removed in [GogLand EAP 16](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2017/10/18/gogland-eap-16-file-watcher-tons-of-new-inspections-smarter-navigate-to-test-and-more/).

In newer versions you have to go to `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `File Watchers` and add `goimports` there.

Answer (score 7):

For those fighting with gofmt on Goland autosave (mat007 comment)

You can double click the item in file watchers to show an edit watcher menu.

Uncheck Auto-save edited files to trigger watcher and it should now only trigger on manual save:

[image]
(Goland 2020.3)